# JSF - xmlns:h not being recognized?

Tags: java, jsf, xml-namespaces

In the "search" XHTML portion of my project, the "h" tags arent being recognized.  I really have no clue why they aren't working.  Any insight? Here's a link to the xhtml file hosted on google code so the entire project can be viewed.

https://code.google.com/p/xdsgui/source/browse/trunk/Frontend/WebContent/search.xhtml

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "they aren't recognized?"  Is your IDE showing an error, or are the pages failing to load?

Comment: When I run search.xhtml on the server, the elements that I define with "h" just don't show up.

Comment: I peeked a bit round in the remaining source code of your project. You've there some pretty painful design mistakes in the code. A `public static InputStream` in the `RequestHandler`? :/ I gather that this is just a hobby project?

Comment: How would you recommend it be structured then?  I'm still a novice, any suggestions would be appreciated greatly.  This project is for an internship and everyone coding it hasn't finished their undergrad yet. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are supposed to be parsed by the `FacesServlet`. If they appear unparsed in the retrieved HTML output, then it simply means that the `FacesServlet` isn't been invoked at all.

Your project's `web.xml` shows that it's been mapped on an URL pattern of `*.jsf`. So if you change the `.xhtml` extension in the request URL of the page in the browser's address bar to `.jsf`, then it'll work.

Better is however to just map the `FacesServlet` on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml` directly. This way you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs and the endusers will also never be able to see the raw JSF source code when they purposefully changes the `.jsf` extension to `.xhtml` in the request URL.

Comment: Thanks much, everything is working as it should be now.