# JSF 2 http://java.sun.com/jsf/html library not found - DEFAULT_SUFFIX not working on Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3

I’m deploying a JSF 2 application on Glassfish 3.1.2 and I having a problem to render page content. None of the jsf 2 new tags are recognized.

Server console shows this error:

```
2014-11-05T08:50:17.436+0100|Advertencia: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.xml.sax.SAXException: PWC6143: No tag "head" defined in tag library associated with uri "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parseCustomAction(JspDocumentParser.java:1202)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.startElement(JspDocumentParser.java:448)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2747)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:222)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:229)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I’ve already check the solutions mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208390/jsf2-registerhostuser-xhtml-9-9-hhead-tag-library-supports-namespace) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770087/jsf-xmlnsh-not-being-recognized):

- No jsf implementation in my web-inf/lib
- Web.xml header version
- Faces-config.xml header version
- My page files are .jspx extension and navigation is make on *.jsf urls (to check DEFAULT_SUFFIX is used correctly)

But they didn't work.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="test" version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<!-- Spring configuration -->
<!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<!-- JSF configuration -->
<!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

And no glassfish-web.xml file.

Finally the error disappeared when I removed the javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX context parameter from web.xml. If I rename my page files to .xhtml and use *.jsf urls in navigation all goes well.

It seems glassfish JSF 2 impl is ignoring DEFAULT_SUFFIX parameter so no other extensions can be use to name view page files.

Glassfish 3.1.2 uses Mojarra 2.1.6, I updated Mojarra to 2.2.8 but it doesn't work either.

Any clue on how to make DEFAULT_SUFFIX work? **This configuration is working on glassfish 2.1.1**.

Answer (score 0):

If your page files contain XHTML then you **should** name then `*.xhtml`. The `.jsf` ending in an URL is only a virtual mapping. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-jsf-pages-with-jsp-or-xhtml-or-jsf-ex) contains detailed information about the differences.

Another option is to map the FacesServlet to the desired file name suffix:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can also map directly to `*.xhtml` if your page files have this suffix.

**See also:**

- [javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598994/javax-faces-default-suffix-not-working)
- [How to use .jsf extension in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120648/how-to-use-jsf-extension-in-urls)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)

Comment: I shoud have mencioned the above configuration is working on Glassfish 2.1.1. The point of DEFAULT_SUFFIX is to let you use other extensions differerent than .jsp or .xhmlt (.jspx in my case), we've been using this parameter in previous Glassfish versions but it seems not working in GF3.

Comment: Ok, but you have an alternative way to specify the extension (servlet-mapping).